# Is the proposed solution to this masonry project okay?

Tags: concrete, stairs, construction

We will going to build long interior, round(little bit) shaped staircase (*similar to this*)[image: STAIRCASE] from *concrete*, and I needed to get instructions
with *physics* that it will possible to make it without any *middle pillar* that 12ft long staircase. So because of that We suppose
to burrow the ground and concrete the base about 2-3ft tall where stair going to start.

I do not have particularly deep knowledge about staircase masonary. After a consulting mason, that he doesn't have a good
alternative. If those solutions aren't reasonable, is there anything we can do that without making middle pillar??
How can we convince him??

Comment: You will need a welded metal (iron rebar) internal structure to support the concrete.

Comment: Google "self supporting stairs" for lots of examples.

Answer (score 8):

If you had an professional engineer design the whole unit as an assembly it may be possible to have the railings and metal concrete reinforcing members in the steps and risers work as a trussed span structure that was only supported at the bottom step and at the top step.

This is definitely not a project for any local neighborhood handyman, general masonry contractor or DIY type work. Also do not expect this type of project to be low cost.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to echo that if you intend to have an unsupported cast concrete staircase, the amount, size, and placement of rebar is likely essential.  This is entirely a question for an engineer.

As a design alternative, you may find that using steel as the structure and adding concrete as treads may be more cost effective.  If you google, I think you can find curved steel staircase manufacturers quite easy.  They may have stock designs that allow you to avoid custom engineering work.

Again, don't expect this to be cheap.